# Add a class name to different classes in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have this structure in an old CSS file:

```
h1.myClass{
color:red;
font-size:18px;
}
h2.myClass{
color:blue;
font-size:16px;
}
h3.myClass{
color:yellow;
font-size:14px;
}
```

and i want to do it in a SASS way (if possible).
some way that i don't have to repeat **myClass** several times. 
maybe, a technique that is similar to nesting in SASS.

Comment: Whoops, this is a better duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841482/how-do-i-reference-the-parent-selector-at-the-end

Answer (score 1):

In SASS it can be done like this:

```
.myClass
  h1&
    color:red;
    font-size:18px;
  h2&
    color:blue;
    font-size:16px;
  h3&
    color:yellow;
    font-size:14px;
```

`&` after selector will take current selector as parent:

```
h1.myClass
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. i'd tried it with curly braces and with not, and i get an error message.