# Sass - if class has this parent

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way with Sass to have nested elements without explicit class names?

To take something like this:

```
.foo {color: blue;}
p.foo {background: yellow;}
span.foo {background: red;}

<p class="foo">Styled paragraph text</p>
<span class="foo">Styled span text</span>
```

And turn it into something like:

```
.foo {
  color: blue;  

  & p {
    background: yellow;
  }

  & span {
    background: red;
  }

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ydynvx7/)

Comment: @cimmanon similar/same question - has better title. mine is likely formatted and posed better

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?   A duplicate is a duplicate, and duplicates should be closed.  The other close voter had no idea what you were even asking, so it clearly wasn't phrased as well as you think it is.

Comment: @cimmanon The question was clear. If all duplicates should be closed, why don't you close the linked duplicate as a duplicate of the "better duplicate"..?

Comment: @JoshCrozier Why are you reopening duplicates?

Comment: @cimmanon You closed it as a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841482/how-do-i-reference-the-parent-selector-at-the-end?lq=1) originally, so I was just trying to find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108103/append-the-parent-selector-to-the-end-with-sass) one instead.. also, I just happened to stumble upon this question when searching through other [related duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301316/how-to-chain-a-class-to-an-element-with-a-parent-selector-in-sass/35301397#35301397)... are you fine with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/286), you can use the following as of SASS v3.3.0:

```
.foo {
  color: blue;  
  @at-root {
    p#{&} {
      background: yellow;
    }
    span#{&} {
      background: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
.foo {
  color: blue;
}
p.foo {
  background: yellow;
}
span.foo {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: A comment explaining the downvote would be appreciated... this outputs the desired results, as demonstrated [here](http://sassmeister.com/).

Comment: I didn't downvote, seems to produce the results I am after.