# How to chain a class to an element with a parent selector in SASS

Tags: sass

I'm trying to do the following with SASS (scss).

```
.class {
  // Base class styles

  a.& {
    // Additions for when applied to a link
  }
}
```

But I get a compiler error:

`Invalid CSS after "a.": expected class name, was "&"`

Any ideas how to achieve this?
Currently I just break out of nesting, but it's sub optimal for my case.

Thanks!

Comment: @cimmanon I was very aware it might have been asked but couldn't find it, and the suggester didn't bring it up neither. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [SASS 3.4](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html), you can use the [`@at-root` directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root) in order to scope the selector to the root.

In addition, you will also need to interpolate the parent selector, `&`, like: `a#{&}`:

```
.class {
  // Base class styles

  @at-root a#{&} {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

Which would compile to:

```
a.class {
  color: #000;
}
```

---

It's worth mentioning that you can nest multiple elements under `@at-root`:

```
.class {
  // Base class styles

  @at-root {
    a#{&} {
      color: #f00;
    }
    p#{&} {
      float: left;
    }
  }
}
```

Which would compile to:

```
a.class {
  color: #f00;
}
p.class {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! That's great that you can use it with or without additional nesting. Any ideas why it's not possible to do the straightforward way in the question?

Comment: Please put in a little more effort towards closing questions that are duplicates, rather than answering them.

Comment: @cimmanon ...I don't frequently answer SASS questions, so I don't know what's been asked. I'm just trying to help out.

Comment: @krulik I'm not sure about the reasoning behind it, because in LESS `a.&` would compile to `a.class` as expected.